# Java polymorphism in openCV

Tags: java, opencv, casting

Ok well, this is probably a silly question, but i'm a little bit rusty in java so... i've extended the Mat class, in order to add new variables. It worked as expected, but when i try to use a method that returns the mother class type and assign it to child class, like this:

```
    Supermat Matchild; <-- (essentially the wrapper class i've made)
    MatChild = (Supermat) imread(name);
```

it returns me this error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opencv.core.Mat cannot be cast to images.Supermat
```

can someone tell me why this happens and if there is a workaround?

Comment: Just because all Supermats are Mats doesn't imply that all Mats are Supermats.

Comment: Exactly - this isn't how polymorphism works.

Comment: You seem to have an error in your variable names. `Matchild` is different from `MatChild`. There is case-sensitivity

Comment: it was just a typo. @GeorgeD

Comment: yes i know, but since SuperMat just adds properties to Mat, i don't see where the problem is.

Comment: If you step back for a second, you could consider that this has nothing at all to do with OpenCV. The problem has basically rooted in the statement you already made: your knowledge of Java is a bit rusty. Of course, one option to "resolve" such problems is to drop a question here. But keep in mind that you are expected to do some prior research yourself. In other words: if your knowledge is limited; don't turn to stackoverflow for **teaching**. Instead, turn to a book or tutorial, and do the **learning** yourself. SO can be a nice detour to avoid that, but that is not what SO is for ...

Comment: i wasn't looking for "ready to use" code, simply there is a problem i stumbled on, and i tought that maybe someone could know a workaround. that's all. btw if someone post a question for example on a basic for loop in C, if your answer is "go look on a manual" in my opinion it's you that don't get the spirit of SO, not me ( no offence intended). Have a  nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your naming and code style are confusing.  Even these two lines are hard to understand.  Learn the Java coding standards.

You said you did this:

```
public class CustomMat extends Mat {
}
```

This means that you can use a `CustomMat` any place in the code where a `Mat` is called for.

```
Mat mat = new CustomMat();
```

Why does this work?  Because a `CustomMat` IS-A `Mat`; that's what inheritance means.

If you're given a `Mat` reference, and you're certain it points to a `CustomMat` instance, you can cast it.  But you've lost the benefit of polymorphism.  It's called the "slicing problem".

Comment: yes, but in this case, don't you loose CustomMat properties ?

Comment: Sry for the bad coding btw, not used to write in java anymore. (i'm pretty rusty as i said)

Comment: Yes you do.  That's called the slicing problem.  If you get a Mat reference, and you know it's pointing to a CustomMat instance, you can cast it.   But you've lost the benefit of polymorphism.

Comment: The problem is, there is a Mat class in opencv libs, but it's not capable to suit my purposes, in the specific, i need to add an attribute int [][] labels,  associated with the Mat elements ( i need labels for a region growing algorithm)

Comment: see there is something that i remember actually xD

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with OpenCV, but if it works like the rest of Java than you may need to implement an Adapter Design Pattern. To my knowledge you cannot cast custom objects the way that you did. The link below has a nice example with a before and after implementation.

[Adapter Design Pattern Example](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter/java/1)

Comment: That was my plan B actually, well i think i'll go with that, thank you very much sir.

Comment: Your very welcome. I had a school project where I learned that the hard way. There are tons of adapter design pattern examples out there, but if you get stuck let me know.